# How to create a full body background that changes every few second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am try to design a page where the body background image changes every few second. I have managed to build the slider but on smaller screens the image does not cover the entire area

[image]

I have tried changing the background attributes but did not work.

Website: https://ag1805x.github.io/

HTML: https://github.com/ag1805x/ag1805x.github.io/blob/master/index.html

CSS: https://github.com/ag1805x/ag1805x.github.io/blob/master/main.css

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see a changing background when I go to the links and it looks fine on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

You are using height 100% on figure tag inside crossfade tag where as all other 3 header, quote and icons class tags are not child of crossfade tag.

Icons lie out side in smaller screens as they body height becomes > 100% and background images has height 100%;

**Try to insert header, quote and icons class tag inside .crossfade div element.** 
Crossfade should be position: relative and adjust all other child elements using position: absolute. They will not lie outside even in small screen as body height will not become > 100%

Comment: Well even I was thinking of something similar but being a novice in HTML/CSS I am not sure how to do it. Can you guide me to some good tutorial on this part?

Comment: Sure , I was not active for last 3 days.

Comment: I have managed to do something else that fixed the problem. Changed to `position : fixed` in `.crossfade`.

Comment: cool, if it fixed the problem, but just fix the name styling as your name "Arindam Ghosh" is overlapping on background and is not clear. Try applying CSS on Name. Here is the line:  <font style="font-family: Times New Roman;font-size: 50px;border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;background-color: #000;color: #fff;padding: 5px 20px;border-radius: 35px;">ARINDAM GHOSH</font>